# How can I see if my bitcoin core money is in my wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I had funds deposited in my bitcoin core account about a year and have still not seen them appear in my wallet. Is there a way I can make sure the transaction went through, and how I can have access to the funds? I have the receiving address where the funds were sent to. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't seen them appear you may be seeing one of two problems:

- Your Bitcoin Core application is not synchronizing with the network properly
- You deposited your Bitcoin to a wrong address

I would find out where the Bitcoin is on the blockchain to be sure; only if you remember the sender of the Bitcoin. You can read up on the technicality of Bitcoin [here](https://bitcoin.org/en/how-it-works).

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that you downloaded the blockchain.
If it's the case and If you are really the **receiver** and you have the **private key**, you can **reindex the chain** by access to the console in the software.
You must convert your private key in WIF (Wallet Import Format) and enter the command `importprivkey("PRIVATE KEY")`.

**How to convert a private key to the WIF ?**

The private key is 32 bytes in hexadecimal format.

1. Take the private key
2. Prepend version number which is a byte in the mainnet equals to **0x80**.
3. Append compression flag which is by default a byte equals to **0x01** but can be **0x00**.
4. Append checksum. Checksum is the first 4 bytes of **double sha256 hash** of whatever is being checkedsum'ed (80 + privKey + 01/00).
5. Base58 encoded data is easier to read and manage. This is reversible. It's available on https://appdevtools.com/base58-encoder-decoder.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://blockchain.info and enter the receiving address into the search at the top right of the screen.  This will show you the details about what transactions have occurred against the address.

This is what the search box looks like:

[image]